# display popup after successful login

Tags: php, html, drupal, drupal-7

I want to display popup after successful login in drupal 7.
I have installed splashify  and colorbox module and enable it as well as included jStorage library in the path '`sites/all/libraries/jstorage`'.

In splashify configuration `'when-  Only show to Anonymous users ','Desktop Settings-Desktop Settings','where-front page','what-display entered test/html full screen','how-open in a lightbox(colorbox)'`.

But it displays on page load before login in mozilla. but in chrome I didn't get any popup even in page load.I have cleard both browser chache and drupal chache.
How to get the popup after successful login and in both browser

Answer (score 4):

you can try below module :

```
https://www.drupal.org/project/popup_onload
```

This module provide rule configuration to display popup on event.

Thanks,
Ankush